# Why is syncing my ipod extremely slow on Ubuntu in comparison to Windows?

Tags: sync, ipod

I've tried both Rhythmbox and Banshee for syncing my iPod Touch 3g.

However it frustrates me that it took them so long to sync up all my songs (~1700). It took around *3~4hours*.

Curious to see how long it took in Windows, I booted into my windows partition and tried to sync my iPod from scratch (using Mediamonkey, apparently iTunes can't import my playlist properly) again with the same amount of songs and to my surprise it only took *~30minutes*, I tested by selecting a few songs to made sure it worked (Rhythmbox failed me once after I finished my sync, the file is there but not playable), and it did!

Has anyone encountered similar problem and has a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Could you describe what part takes so much time? E.g., with me in Banshee, the 'converting' takes ages. Thanks.

Comment: I believe its the 'converting' part. It is the part where it says "Adding track # of #ofsongs. It would take around 5~10s to convert one audio mp3 file. Based on rough calculation it would take 166 minutes to transfer 2000 songs if every conversion is done in 5s

Comment: Try to reset your iPod Touch 3G to factory settings. After that, sync it with Banshee. It seems like Banshee can't sync properly if the iPod has been synchronised with iTunes first.

Comment: I've just tested restoring my ipod, after which I used itunes solely for restoring my data (nothing involving music). Went back to banshee and its the same. [Side note] Under device properties it wrote 'Encode to: MP3 (LAME Encoder)' with 128kbps constant bitrate, its the only choice I have.

Comment: Mm. What happens when you restore the data afterwards? On SuperUser, someone has posted a workaround for the converting using `gtkpod`. You might want to take a look at it. http://superuser.com/questions/292647/how-to-disable-conversion-when-syncing-ipod-with-banshee

Comment: gtkpod gave me problem (blank window). I was slow to realise that when it is syncing, it is not actually syncing due to libimobiledevice not supporting ios 5.1.1 music sync yet. Downgrading to ios 4 made sync work again, however the slow sync problem still exists, alongside with data restore problems. I made a workaround which is syncing using virtualbox windows guest, not the most ideal, but I guess I'll leave this as it is.

Comment: That's too bad. I hope that a real solution will be posted here in the future.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!